# Multiple Alarm for multiple Alarm Manager Object

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to create three Alarm named as Reminder1, Reminder2, Reminder3.
I know that, I can create multiple alarm for three of the above using different requestCode. Corresponding code was embedded below

```
private void startReminderAlarm(int id, Calendar from_date, long interval) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent remIntent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    remIntent = new Intent(mContext, ReminderReceiver.class);
    remIntent.putExtra("ID", id);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, id, remIntent, 0);
    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, from_date.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Alarm Set for id" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "Alarm Set for id: " + id);
}
```

Depending on the id of Reminder, I'm starting each alarm. This was working fine. My question is,

1) Reminder1 alarm to be set for daily morning.

2) Reminder2 to be set for Daily Twice.

3) Reminder3 to be set for Daily Thrice.

1st case, wont create a problem, because it shall be set only once with corresponding id.

2nd case, If I create two alarm with corresponding id, the last one only persists. First one will be discarded.

3rd case, If I create three alarm with corresponding id, the last one only persists. First and second will be discarded.

I want to create 2 or 3 separate alarms with particular id.

Please suggest me any solution to solve this.

Comment: Do you mean the Reminder2 has the same id as Reminder3?

Comment: No, both are having different id. But Reminder2 itself i want to set two times per day(morning, night). For that i have to use same id right?
Like that, Reminder3 also, i want to set three times per day(morning, afternoon and night).

Comment: I think `setInexactRepeating` can work if you set the interval to like 12 hours.

Comment: But, If i use the interval as default one, it will be work. Here the interval between, morning- afternoon, afternoon-night and night-morning are irrelevant. In this case, I couldn't use interval as constant one.

Comment: Could you explain how you want Reminder2  to be set twice a day. For example 10A.M. and 15P.M.

Comment: Yes exactly. Reminder2 is to be set for 9.00AM and 20.00PM, Reminder3 is to be set for  9.00AM, 13.00PM and 20.00PM

Comment: I post an answer. You can try if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `intent.setData` to distinguish the intents. That is

```
remIntent = new Intent(mContext, ReminderReceiver.class);
remIntent.putExtra("ID", id);
remIntent.setData(Uri.parse("reminder:"+id+"/"+from_date.getTimeInMillis()+"/"+interval));
```